# How to extract a substring as a new column using Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala

I want to extract names from two columns in one table and join it with another table. If the name in the 'name' column is 'NOT FOUND', I would like to extract it from the 'Description' column.

The 'Description' column will follow 3 patterns:

1. Name was not found. Name :ab33c and client

   So in this case I want to extract ab33c out.
2. Name j2fc_being was not found:j2fc_being_decom_2017

   I want to extract j2fc out.
3. Name w3fkk was not found:Summary:

   I want to extract w3fkk out.

Below are the codes I write:

```
SELECT inc.name, inc.Description, inc.new_name, srv.dv_category, srv.virtual,
FROM ( 
SELECT inc.name, inc.Description, 
CASE 
  WHEN inc.name NOT LIKE 'NOT FOUND%' THEN inc.name
  WHEN inc.Description LIKE '%Name :%' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(inc.Description, '.*Name :(.+)(\s).*','\1')
  WHEN inc.Description LIKE 'Name%being%' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(inc.Description, '.*(\s)(.+)_.+','\1') 
  WHEN inc.Description LIKE 'Name%was%' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(inc.Description, '.*(\s)(.+)(\s).+','\1') 
  ELSE inc.name
  END as new_name
FROM incident inc
) inc
LEFT JOIN server srv 
ON inc.new_name = srv.dv_name
```

The context will be Impala SQL.
Could I get some help on how to extract? Thank you very much.

Comment: The syntax issue should be resolved by removing `CASE ( 
SELECT inc.name, inc.Description, ` and `FROM incident inc
) ` (basically move the case statement inside brackets to the outside)

Comment: @ZLK Thank you for your reply! I tried removing it, but I will get an exception : AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference: 'inc.ci_name'. I am thinking that this may be due to it is joining the two tables before creating the new column in inc table?

Comment: What does your full query look like now?

Comment: @ZLK I have edited in the question, thank you very much!

Comment: @BMY In your updated query, I don't see a reference to `inc.ci_name` anywhere; frankly, it appears valid. If this question is unresolved and you have an updated version of the full query with your AnalysisException error, I'd be happy to help.